# How to update Line series Chart with data consistently?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I have a simple line series chart using WPFToolKit. I would like to have new data coming in to be updated on the chart every 5 minutes. But I have no idea how to go about it. The way I am showing data now is this.

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showColumnChart();
    }


    private void showColumnChart()
    {
         List<KeyValuePair<double,double>> Power = new List<KeyValuePair<double, double>>();
        Power.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(30, 40));
        Power.Add(new KeyValuePair<double,double>(50, 60));
        //Setting data for line chart
      lineChart.DataContext = Power;

    }
```

Also, do I have to use a database? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Check for System.Windows.Forms.Timer and inside the delegate, call your method which would update the data on the chart.

Comment: Consider that we are talkung aboyt WPF, would suggest to use Ststem.Timers.Timer instead. Avoid WindowsForms reference, if you can.

Comment: But I would like to have the x axis which is the 5minute interval to correspond to the data. Sorry if I was not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPfTimer09292009090518AM/WPfTimer.aspx (using Dispatcher Timer, you can achieve that).

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't figure out how to update the graph with incoming data. Sorry I am new at this..